# Using packager resolver for external jar

Tags: java, ivy, jsoup

I've been trying to download an external jar Jsoup by creating a packager.xml file.
When I try to building the file I get back an error which says

> ".......ivy2\packager\build\org.jsoup\jsoup\1.6.1\packager.xml is not
>   a valid XML document"

The following are the changes I've made in my ivysettings.xml

```
<settings defaultResolver="default"/>

    <resolvers>
       <ibiblio name="default" m2compatible="true"/>
        <packager name="packager" buildRoot="${user.home}/.ivy2/packager/build" resourceCache="${user.home}/.ivy2/packager/cache" preserveBuildDirectories="false">
            <ivy pattern="file:///${ivy.settings.dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"/>
            <artifact pattern="file:///${ivy.settings.dir}/packager.xml"/>
        </packager>
    </resolvers>
    <modules>
        <module organisation="org.jsoup" name="jsoup" resolver="packager"/>
    </modules>
```

the following is the packager.xml file that I created,

```
<packager-module version="1.0">
<property name="name" value="${ivy.packager.module}"/>
    <property name="version" value="${ivy.packager.revision}"/>
<property name="packagename" value="${name}-${version}"/>

    <resource dest="archive" url="http://jsoup.org/$packagename.jar" />

    <build>
      <move file="archive/${packagename}.jar" tofile="artifacts/jars/${name}.jar"/>
    </build>
</packager-module>
```

The error,

[ivy:resolve] :: org.jsoup#jsoup;1.6.1: C:\blah....\blah.ivy2\packager\build\org.jsoup\jsoup\1.6.1\packager.xml is not a valid XML document.

I've tried doing all I could to make it a valid xml document but still the error doesn't revert......Can you please give some insight into this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've reproduced the error.

The **packager.xml** file is failing it's XML schema validation check.

```
[ivy:retrieve] [xmlvalidate] /home/mark/.ivy2/packager/build/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.6.1/packager.xml:6:72: 
     cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'sha1' must appear on element 'resource'.
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] /home/mark/.ivy2/packager/build/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.6.1/build.xml:23: /home/mark/.ivy2/packager/build/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.6.1/packager.xml is not a valid XML document.
```

When troubleshooting the [packager resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/packager.html) I'd suggest setting *preserveBuildDirectories* attribute to "true" which enables you to see the intermediate files generated. Very clever stuff there....

## Revised packager file

This is not the only problem. I finally got the packager to work as follows:

```
<packager-module version="1.0">
    <property name="name" value="${ivy.packager.module}"/>
    <property name="version" value="${ivy.packager.revision}"/>
    <property name="packagename" value="${name}-${version}"/>

    <resource dest="archive" url="http://jsoup.org/packages/jsoup-1.6.1.jar" sha1="b65281e9d00f255cdfab9e1880f7fc7a1fb1bffb"/>

    <build>
        <jar basedir="archive" destfile="artifacts/jars/${name}.jar"/>
    </build>
</packager-module>
```

The packager is really designed for unwrapping tar or zip archives containing jars. That is why I had to repack the jar file, downloaded by the packager resolver, in the example above.

## Observation

You do know that you don't need the packager resolver at all? [jsoup is available from Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jsoup%7Cjsoup%7C1.6.1%7Cjar)? I point this out because you already have an [ibilio resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/ibiblio.html) configured in your ivy settings file.....

If you really want jsoup from it's project homepage I'd suggesting using the simpler [url resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/url.html)

Comment: Thanks Mark, appreciate your work and efforts :).......I'm new to the maven and ivy stuff and started learning out a few days ago....I initially thought packager resolver was the only way to go about but realized there were other resolvers too slowly, but surely, which would satiate my needs....I got the above working using ibiblio resolver.....once again I appreciate your effort, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `packager.xml` file contains malformed XML - it has nothing to do with Ivy or JSoup, the problem is with the format of the file itself.

The snippet of `packager.xml` you posted looks okay, but I'm guessing it's not the whole file contents. You're welcome to post here the whole file.

You can use an XML-aware editor in order to understand where the problem is - such as an IDE (e.g. Eclipse) or a standalone XML editor.

Alternatively, you can find the offending section by trial-and-error: remove small portions of the file until the error disappears and you find the offending line.

Comment: that is the whole content of the packager.xml file. When I tried debugging, it shows no error....but only when I try building it, the issue props up......